# Weblogic SOAP web service deployment issue

Tags: web-services, soap, deployment, apache-axis, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy SOAP web service war on weblogic server(12) but during deployment I am getting the following exception:

```
exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:could not initialize class org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.TempFileManager
```

Answer (score 0):

The wls-cat.war give you that class load